# Unexpected behaviour from Gson

Tags: json, gson, java-9, jlink, jdeps

I developed a small application that stores data coming from a device: I chose to store data in JSON format, and the serialization/deserialization of the data works just fine, even if it involves some custom types created by me...but only I work in the IDE ([Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), for that matter).

When I export a runnable JAR file though, the deserialization of the data encounters some kind of problem, because the software always throws this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot allocate class LocalDateTime
    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$4.newInstance(UnsafeAllocator.java:104)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:225)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
```

I thought I'd encounter problems with custom types, not a built-in one. At this point, I discovered two things:

- if I use a full JRE 9 to run the JAR file, the exception is not thrown: I double checked the modules included in the custom JRE I created with Jlink.exe, and everything is included correctly. I still want to use a smaller JRE, so I did not investigate further yet (I guess this explains why in the IDE it works perfectly)
- I added a custom deserializer to the Gson object (see below), with which I simply manually converted the JSON string into a valid data, and that avoided the exception on the LocalDateTime class...but the exception reappeared simply on another class, this time a custom-made one.

At this point, I guess I can simply add a deserializer for each data type that causes problem, but I'm wondering **why the issue won't happen with a full JRE, and why a smaller JRE causes this**, even if all the modules required are included. Maybe it's worth mentioning also that I added no custom serializer to the Gson object that saves the data, it is all serialized as per Gson default.

`LocalDateTime` deserializer:

```
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, java.lang.reflect.Type type,
                JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject joDate = json.getAsJsonObject().get("date").getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject joTime = json.getAsJsonObject().get("time").getAsJsonObject();
        //JSON example: {"date":{"year":2019,"month":1,"day":9},"time":{"hour":6,"minute":14,"second":1,"nano":0}
        return LocalDateTime.of(joDate.get("year").getAsInt(),
                joDate.get("month").getAsInt(),
                joDate.get("day").getAsInt(),
                joTime.get("hour").getAsInt(),
                joTime.get("minute").getAsInt(),
                joTime.get("second").getAsInt(),
                joTime.get("nano").getAsInt());
    }
}
```

Jdeps.deps modules list:

```
com.google.gson
java.base
javafx.base
javafx.controls
javafx.fxml
javafx.graphics
org.slf4j
```

---

After the answer I received, I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1695#issue-620851907).

Comment: Before going into this, if you could make the project available, that would make debugging a lot easier. :)

Comment: @Nicolai I did not add more code since the issue seemed related to a generic serialization/deserialization of the LocalDateTime class, and my code seemed quite irrelevant since it uses only default settings for GSON

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR

You need a runtime image (e.g. full JDK or something built with jlink) that includes the module *jdk.unsupported*.

## Full Answer

GSON wants to create instances of classes it deserializes without calling any constructors (so nothing gets initialized without GSON saying so). This can't normally be done, but `sun.misc.Unsafe` offers a way to do this with the method `allocateInstance`. To that end, GSON needs an instance of `sun.misc.Unsafe`. The topmost frame in the call stack is from `UnsafeAllocator`, which uses [common trickery to get `Unsafe`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/UnsafeAllocator.java#L40).

The problem is, `sun.misc.Unsafe` is in  module *jdk.unsupported*, which is present in a full JDK but you won't usually find in runtime images.

When creating your runtime image with jlink, make sure to include the option `--add-modules jdk.unsupported` and you should be good to go.

Arguably, GSON should declare an [optional dependency](https://blog.codefx.org/java/module-system-optional-dependencies/) on *jdk.unsupported* with `requires static`.

Comment: Great effort on debugging the problem +1

Comment: It worked, I just created a new JRE including `jdk.unsupported` and GSON doesn't throw any exception. In any case, the exception was thrown only for the two classes I mentioned in the question, so it was solved by two deserialziers. Should I notify GSON developers of this optional dependency?

Comment: Glad I could help. Yeah opening an issue is a good idea, although there's an important details that needs to be discussed - better there than here, though. Please leave a link once the issue was opened.

Comment: Why should the dependency on `jdk.unsupported` be optional? Wouldn't a regular dependency be better because apparently without `Unsafe`, Gson's functionality is limited.

Comment: This should be discussed on the GSON issue. Short answer: The presence of _jdk.unsupported_ should not be relied upon (notice its name) and since GSON works without it (just not as comfortable), avoiding a strict dependency would be a good choice IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue when packing `compose` a desktop application.

update `build.gradle` file, add an `unsupported`  module.

```
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "admin"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
            modules("java.sql")
            modules("jdk.unsupported")
        }
    }
}
```